# How to retrieve values from database?

Tags: list, prolog

I have the following lists in Prolog:

```
fruit(banana, yellow, curvy, 4).
fruit(apple, green, round, 2).
fruit(kiwifruit, green, round, 7).
fruit(mango, orange, round, 1).
fruit(watermelon, red, round, 8).
```

And I want a query that would return all the green fruits. How do I do this? I played around with [`findall/3` and `bagof/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.29%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/allsolutions.html%27%29%29) but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
fruit(Fruit, green, Shape, Count).
```

This will return all fruit/4 rules which have a 2nd value of 'green', and will you the values for the 1st, 3rd, and 4th values.

Comment: Brilliant, that's what I was after. I knew I was over thinking it. Cheers.

Comment: Is there a way to add more parameters to that query? Like all the green and round fruit for example?

Comment: It wouldn't let me edit the above comment but I sorted that out as well. I thought `fruit(F, green, round, C).` wasn't working, but I just had a typo in it. Thanks again

Comment: @sifRAWR right, and now you can call `findall( _F-_C, fruit(_F, green, round, _C), X).` to get the list `X` of all the green and round fruits.